# How to control service visibility

Tags: java, osgi

Is there a way to control the visibility on services based on the filter of the listener?

I was disappointed to realize that the EventHook service can only control which **bundles** receive a ServiceEvent. Shouldn't it be which **listeners** receive the event? Instead of a collection of contexts it should be a collection of something similar to ListenerHook.ListenerInfo.

Is there another way I can control which listeners receive the events? I want to enforce a compulsory filter property to receive services, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Core 4.3 we add EventListenerHook which replaces EventHook. It will let 
>   you filter at the listener level. This is currently implemented in the 
>   Equinox 3.7 builds if you wish to experiment with it.

Quote of BJ Hargrave from an answer to the same question on osgi-dev maillist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleContext.addServiceListener(ServiceListener, String)
```